# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean when i click button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've just checked a NIM on database. If the nim exists I can insert on database, but if it doesn't exist, I cannot insert on database.
Here my code:

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {

            connection.Open();


            var checkQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM datauser WHERE NIM = @NIM";

            using (var checkCommand = new SqlCommand(checkQuery, connection))
            {

                checkCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIM", txtnim.Text);

                bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(checkCommand.ExecuteScalar());

                if (!exists)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Maaf Nama dengan Nim= "+txtnim.Text+" tidak ada ..","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Sudah benarkah data yang anda masukkan ?", "Simpan Data", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            if (txtsukarela.Text == "")
                                txtsukarela.Text = "0";
                            if (txtwajib.Text == "")
                                txtwajib.Text = "0";
                            if (txtkredit.Text == "")
                                txtkredit.Text = "0";
                            int saldo =(( Convert.ToInt32(txtwajib.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtsukarela.Text)) - Convert.ToInt32(txtkredit.Text));
                            cmd.Connection = conn;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO datauser values(@NIM,@Wajib,@Sukarela,@Kredit,@Saldo,@tgl)";

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIM", txtnim.Text.ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wajib", Convert.ToInt32(txtwajib.Text));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sukarela", Convert.ToInt32(txtsukarela.Text));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kredit", Convert.ToInt32(txtkredit.Text));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saldo", saldo);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tgl", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/d HH:mm:ss"));

                            conn.Open(); //opening connection
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //executing query
                            conn.Close();

                            MessageBox.Show("Simpanan berhasil Dimasukkan", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                                Response.Redirect("Simpanan.aspx");

                        }



                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but when i click add it throwns

```
// Check if it exists
                bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(checkCommand.ExecuteScalar()); -->String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

here my aspx.code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="box col-md-12">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <div class="box-header well" data-original-title="">
                <h2>Tambah Simpanan</h2>

                <div class="box-icon">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="NIM"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtnim" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvNIM" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required & dan harus 10 digit"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtnim"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Harus angka & 10 digit" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10,10}" ControlToValidate="txtnim"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="WAJIB"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtwajib" runat="server" Width="100%" OnTextChanged="txtwajib_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Harus Diisi"
                                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="txtwajib"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Nama"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtnama" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Sukarela"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtsukarela" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Kredit"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtkredit" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                         <td>
                             <asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="Tambah" OnClick="btnadd_Click" />
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any sugestion to that ??

Comment: well `"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM datauser WHERE NIM = @NIM"` doesn't really return a scalar.  How are you hoping to convert that to a boolean?  Honestly just debug it and see what `checkCommand.ExecuteScalar()` returns for a start

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var checkQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM datauser WHERE NIM = @NIM";
> ...
> bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(checkCommand.ExecuteScalar());
> ```

It seems like you're trying to determine if the query returns any rows.  `ExecuteScalar` returns the value from the first column in the first row.  A better method would be:

```
var checkQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 NIM FROM datauser WHERE NIM = @NIM";
...
bool exists = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkCommand.ExecuteScalar()) ;
```